# What's the use of second 'is' in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Thus, everyone's task is as unique as is his specific opportunity to implement it.

> *The 7 Habits of Highly Effective People*

I don't understand the grammar of the sentence especially the second 'is'.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rather literary use of *as* introduces a parallel clause with inversion, and means something like "and similarly"

So

> as is [his specific opportunity to implement it)

means roughly

> and [his specific opportunity to implement it] is similarly unique.

Even with this wording, the long subject would allow [extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition),
giving

> and similarly unique is [his specific opportunity to implement it].

**Edit**

I did not notice that either Stephen Covey (in *7 Habits*) or you have misquoted Viktor Frankl, who wrote

> Thus, everyone’s task is unique as is his specific opportunity to implement it.

Note that there is no *as* before "unique"

With both *as's*, this naturally reads as a use of the pattern *as X as Y*, and what follows the second *as* should be a noun phrase, and the *is* seems out of place.

However the meaning of this mangled sentence is I'm sure not what Frankl intended, and probably not what Covey intended either.

> Thus, everyone's task is as unique as his specific opportunity to implement it.

is apparently specifying how unique everyone's task is: it's unique to the same degree as his specific opportunity to implement it.

Maybe you can understand what that might mean: I can't.

Comment: Is there any difference if we remove the second 'is'? "everyone's task is as unique as his specific opportunity to implement it.

Comment: The sentence as you quoted, with _as_ before and after _unique_, is barely parsable with the _is_, and doesn't make any sense without it. Frankl's original quotation has only one _as_. I have edited my answer to explain this.

Comment: So, is this sentence "everyone's task is as unique as is his specific opportunity to implement it." still grammatical?

Comment: It is grammatical,  but with an awkward and unlikely interpretation. With the _is_ making what follows the second _as_ a clause, the two _as's_ cannot be correlative. The predicate of the first clause is _as unique_, with no complement, so it only makes sense if it means "as unique as whatever has just been mentioned". So it must mean something like "the task is as unique as whatever we mentioned before, and his opportunity is as unique as both of those".